# What is contained in the controlfile of oracle database?

Tags: oracle-11g

As we all know that controlfile contains datafile locations and redo log locations along with their names.It also contains dbname,timestamp,checkpoint info,log sequence number,rman backup info.In addition to this,what more a controlfile contains? Does it contain user backup info?

Answer (score -1):

Lets define the `controlfile` in oracle: it is a small binary file that records the physical structure of the database and its include:

1) The database name.

2) Names and locations of associated datafiles and redo log files.

3) The timestamp of the database creation

4) The current log sequence number

5) Checkpoint information

Comment: Other than the above,what more does it contain?

Comment: in my post I wrote everything the control file include

Comment: Not everything. Check `V$CONTROLFILE_RECORD_SECTION` view. There are much more different records.

Comment: @MindaugasRiauba please check http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/control001.htm#ADMIN11281 and advise thanks

Comment: This doc lists what must be in controlfile but not all the possible info. The simpliest example is information about backups and copies which is stored only in controlfile if you do not use RMAN catalog database.